# Time Independent Schrödinger Equation meaning

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian

Working on some QM and we realised we don't understand the simple equation is for the wavefunction.

$H \psi(x) = E \psi(x)$

We know $H$ is the hamiltonian, the sum of the kinetic and potential energies of the particle (?), but what does $E$ represent? The eigenvalues of energy?

Any help would be great, QM hurts my head, cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. $H$ is the Hamiltonian operator, $\psi$ its eigenfunction and $E$ its eigenvalue.

When the result of an operator, $H$, acting on a function, $\psi$, is proportional to the function itself, $\psi$ is an eigenfunction and the proportionality factor, $E$, is the eigenvalue.

**Note.** $H$ is an operator, not a function. So $H$ can be interpreted as the sum of the kinetic energy operator and the potential energy operator,

$H = -\dfrac{\hbar^2}{2m} \nabla^2 + V(\mathbf{r})$,

for a particle of mass $m$ in the potential field $V(\mathbf{r})$

Comment: So its kind of the same process as $Au=\lambda u$, in how E is just a constant of proportionality when $H$ acts on the system $\psi$?

Comment: pretty the same. Usually eigenproblems are introduced in linear algebra, where $A$ is a matrix, $u$ is a vector, and $\lambda$ is a real or complex number.